# XML " expected at line 50 char 35?

Tags: xml

After starting to write XML last week, I wanted to try modding Friday Night Funkin. After attempting to run the mod it gives me this error;

> haxe.xml.XmlParserException: Expected " at line 50 char 35

When I went to the line it stated was causing the error, it was in the middle of a statement.

Line 50: `<SubTexture name="BF NOTE RIGHT0000" x="1299" y="0" width="418" height="545" frameX="47" frameY="155" frameWidth="418" frameHeight="545"/>`

Comment: That line does not contain the error.  Post the entire file (or preferably the smallest version of the file that still exhibits the issue).  You probably forgot a quote or used a curly quote by mistake earlier in the file.

Comment: Consider using an XML editor rather than a general text editor. It makes it much easier to locate most basic typos.